# python call from string with different string formats

Tags: python

I am turning mad with the following code :

```
methods = {
    'pageFunctionNewPage': myClassInstance.pageFunctionNewPage,
}
sf = 'NewPage,1,0'
functionName1 = 'PageFunction' + sf.split(',')[0]
functionName2 = 'pageFunctionNewPage'
print functionName1
print functionName2
methods[functionName1]()
methods[functionName2]()
```

The two prints are same on screen. The second call works well while the first one always send an error message

```
KeyError: 'PageFunctionNewPage'
```

Really cannot see what I do wrong ! Tks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: Also consider this function, which can make your code easier to read, and no need to re invent the wheel http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"pageFunctionNewPage" != "PageFunctionNewPage"
```

You probably made a typo in `functionName1 = 'PageFunction' + sf.split(',')[0]`

Comment: Argh I hate TYP0 ! Tks